# laravel notification: how to mark as read specific data['cartId']?

Tags: laravel, laravel-notification

I have a database notification where type is `customerOrderNorification`.

in this notificaion I put data `cartId`:

```
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'cartId' => $this->cartItem->id,
    ];
}
```

I want to when a seller accept one order, system make all notification of all users markAsRead where `data['cartId'] == $specific_id`.

how to do this ?

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far and if so, please provide your attempt and specific detail of where you're stuck.

Comment: I founded one way to do this, making notification `model` and set the query on the model to access the `notifications table`